How can I go through all possible numbers in one loop?
I am quite new with R and trying to turn a larger SpatRaster into SpatVector.
Unfortunately using
vec <- as.polygons(raster)
I get Error: [as.polygons] the raster is too large
So I figured I can make smaller tiles and afterwards bind the vectors together again.
my code so far looks like this (training raster is much smaller and could be polygonized without making tiles)
f <- system.file("ex/logo.tif", package = "terra")
r <- rast(f)

r_tiles <- makeTiles(r, c(34,51), filename = "training/tile_.tif") 

for(i in 1:length(r_tiles)) {                                                                           
  raster <- assign(paste0("tile_",i), rast(paste("training/tile_",i,".tif", sep = "")))                      #kleine Raster wieder einlesen
  polygon <- as.polygons(raster, aggregate = F)
  writeVector(polygon, filename = paste("training/pol_",i,".gpkg", sep = ""))
  assign(paste0("pol_",i), vect(paste("training/pol_",i,".gpkg", sep = "")))  
}

What I want to do now is bind all the smaller vectors together to again have one bigger SpatVector with the same dimensions as the original raster.
I know I could do
bigPol <- rbind(pol_1, pol_2, pol_3, pol_4, pol_5, pol_6) 
But is there a smoother way maybe using some sort of loop?
I thought something like
for(j in 1: length(r_tiles)){bigPol <- rbind(paste0("pol_", i, sep = "")
But of course this doesn't work.

Welcome to SO!  A for loop and assign may work, but - as you say - it's clunky.  A more r-ish way of doing things would be to convert the body of the loop to a function and use lapply.  You could then do the binding at the same time.  For example, something like bigPol <- rbindlist(lapply(seq_len(r_tiles), myLoopFunction)).  There are plenty of examples of converting for loops to calls to lapply on this site and elsewhere.

Thanks! It looks much smoother. I now tried
loopfunction_train <-  function(i) paste0("pol_", i, sep = "") bigPol <- rbind(list(lapply(seq_len(r_tiles), loopfunction_train))) and get the error
Error in seq_len(r_tiles) :
argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In seq_len(r_tiles) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
2: In lapply(seq_len(r_tiles), loopfunction_train) :
NAs introduced by coercion.
Do you know how to solve that?

Sorry. Try seq_len(length(r_tiles)). Otherwise, explore how to get the length of r_tiles. I’ve never worked with rasters, alas.

That worked for getting the right length, I still had problems getting the right format, so I could use it in 'rbind()'.

Now I found a way to work around it, by just putting everything in the first loop:
for(i in 1:length(r_tiles)) {                                                                            raster <- assign(paste0("tile_",i), rast(paste("training/tile_",i,".tif", sep = ""))) polygon <- as.polygons(raster, aggregate = F) writeVector(polygon, filename = paste("training/pol_",i,".gpkg", sep = "")) assign(paste0("pol_",i), vect(paste("training/pol_",i,".gpkg", sep = ""))) if(i==1) big_poly = polygon if(i>1) big_poly = rbind(big_poly, polygon) }

That might work, but it is very inefficient.  The problem will be with big_poly = rbind(big_poly, polygon), particularly if the big part of the object name is accurate.  You really, really, should move the bind outside the loop.  See, for example, Chapter 3 of The R Inferno.

Following the recommendations, you can apply an r-ish function to get this job done:
library(terra)

f <- system.file("ex/logo.tif", package = "terra")
r <- rast(f)

r_tiles <- makeTiles(r, c(34,51),  filename = "training/tile_.tif")

path = 'training'
list.files(path, pattern = '.tif$', full.names = T)

polygonize = function(fname, out_path){
  r = rast(fname)
  polygon = as.polygons(r, aggregate = F)
  filename = gsub('.tif','.shp',basename(fname))
  writeVector(polygon, filename = file.path(out_path, filename))
}

sapply(r_tiles, polygonize, out_path = path)

Then, it's easy as loading the files in a list and then use vect again:
vects = list.files(path, pattern = '.shp$', full.names = T)

vs = lapply(vects, function(x){vect(x)})

v = vect(vs)

plot(v)


